# How to convert blob into base64 in nextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, blob, filereader, nextjs-image

I am getting the Image from an API response. I am trying to the get the image and display in the UI.

```
import FileReader from  'filereader';

export default async (req, res) => {
const { method } = req;
switch (method) {
case 'GET':
    try {
        const response = await fetch("imagepathurl", Constants.config);
        const imageBlob = await response.blob()
        console.log("imageBlob", imageBlob)
        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob);
        });
     } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
    break

default:
  res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH'])
  res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`)
}
}
```

I can able to capture imageBlob but from the fileReader() i am unable to capture and convert to base64.
In File Reader i am facing `Error: cannot read as File: {}`.

Please let me know the way i am doing is correct or can soneone guide me in fixing it.

Comment: create a state for image blob and another for the image URL then use `setImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(imgBlob))`

Comment: What i setImageURL and URL in your case

Comment: `const [imageURL, setImageUrl] = React.useState('')`

Comment: There is no need of setImageUrl always the url is same. From the API Url i am getting an image in the response need to capture that image and convert to base64. From response,  blob i am getting . From blob how to convert to base64

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Blob to Base64 in NodeJS without FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099802/blob-to-base64-in-nodejs-without-filereader)? Your code runs on the server, but `FileReader` is a Web API only available in the browser.

Comment: this method converts your blob format to a "url" for your image tag to understand and you use `imageURL` state to keep the data. it isn't a traditional url pointing to a server