# How can I convert an blob to base64 in node typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am getting a blob image in response to an internal call to a MicroService in node ts.
I want to convert it to a Base64 so that I can use it to display it in an EJS image tag.

I have tried to do it with the Buffer but the base64 it's giving me is incorrect.

```
response = Buffer.from(response,'binary').toString('base64');
```

I have also tried the FileReader but getting an error that FileReader is undefined.

Comment: Why not use an Object URL for the blob instead?  Far more efficient.

Comment: Hi can you please give me some reference links.

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62684503/13093769)

```
const b64 = await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.buffer())
      .then((buffer) => {
        const b64 = buffer.toString('base64');
        return b64;
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```