# ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined in node js (nest js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert my image to base64. So I create this function for this.
But the problem is when I try to run my program I have an error called **ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined**. I have no idea what is this error about.

This is my code..?

```
const toDataURL = url => fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = reject
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
  });
)


toDataURL('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0')
  .then(dataUrl => {
    console.log('RESULT:', dataUrl)
  })
```

Comment: It is because FileReader is part of web API not of javascript so it is not available in nodejs instead of this you can use the fs module available in nodejs you can read about fs on official nodejs docs

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54099802/4225384

Answer (score 2):

FileReader is part of Web API in a browser but not in Node.js
Try to use native Node.js method to read from a file or try to search an appropriate npm package